# 1in3SAT explanation

Tags: algorithms

I'm reading online about 1in3SAT that's NP-complete

This is their explanation

[image: Claim and Proof]

My question is for part 2 where we prove 1in3Sat is NP-Hard

why do we add 4 new variables to produce three new clauses?

Comment: Image was not included

Comment: I think it is a trick to transform the given 3SAT formula $\phi$ into a 1in3SAT formula $\phi'$ such that $\phi$ is satisfiable exactly when $\phi'$ is satisfiable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hope is that the following two things are true:

1. For each assignment of values to $x_{i1}$, $x_{i2}$, $x_{i3}$ satisfying the original clause $x_{i1} \vee x_{i2} \vee x_{i3}$, there is a further assignment of values to $a_i$, $b_i$, $c_i$, $d_i$ such that the 1-in-3 clauses corresponding to $\{\overline{x_{i1}}, a_i, b_i\}$, $\{x_{i2}, b_i, c_i\}$, and $\{\overline{x_{i3}}, c_i, d_i\}$ are all satisfied.
2. For each assignment of values to $x_{i1}$, $x_{i2}$, $x_{i3}$, $a_i$, $b_i$, $c_i$, $d_i$ satisfying the 1-in-3 clauses, $x_{i1} \vee x_{i2} \vee x_{i3}$ holds, and the original clause is satisfied.

If you can prove these things, then that means the triple of 1-in-3 clauses is just a way to simulate a normal 3SAT clause. It's a bit like using NAND gates to simulate OR, AND, and NOT gates.

We use separate variables $a_i$, $b_i$, $c_i$, $d_i$ for each clause so that we have complete freedom in step 1 above: what we do for one clause doesn't affect how we can deal with the other clauses.